# Insert CSV files based on field name

Tags: mysql, csv, ftp

Now am using the below code to upload CSV files into MYSQL database via FTP.It's Working fine.The CSV column have a field name "STATUS". It's have two values A and D. But i want to insert particular rows only based on field "STATUS" A. How can i insert this?.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/782012_10.csv'
 INTO TABLE tbl_dndno
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: you can't do it by `mysql load`. options are use filters like `awk` to filter csv or use temporary constraint on the table.

Comment: @tuxuday Can you please give us a sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

You could load the file into a temporary table, then insert from the temporary table into your main table with a query that selects the rows you want.